# Why is the move constructor invoked only once?

Tags: c++, constructor, move

I have the following function:

```
SomeClass func()
{
    SomeClass someObject;
    someObject.mutate("some text");
    return someObject;
}
```

and the following two cases:

## 1

```
int main()
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

## 2

```
int main()
{
    SomeClass someObject = func();
    return 0;
}
```

I have NRVO turned off, no copy/move elision occurs.

In both cases I have the same output:

```
"default constructor"
"move constructor"
```

Why is the move constructor invoked only once in case 2? I would have expected to be called once for the return value of the function and second to initialize someObject variable.

UPDATE: To be more clear: the output is for debug build. For release build I only have "default constructor" and this seems clear to me due to copy/move elision. I want to understand the different output for the debug build.

Comment: Are you building as C++17? Had NRVO been on you would not have seen the move c'tor called at all.

Comment: Are you sure about "no copy/move elision occurs"? Because NRVO is only a subset of copy elision.

Comment: The output is for the debug build. For the release build I only have "default constructor" for both cases, and that makes sense because copy/move elision happens there due to optimization. So, I think I can safely assume, due to different output, the copy/move elision does not happen for the debug build.

Comment: That's an unfounded assumption. There are still quite a few optimizations a compiler will do even in a debug build. Mainly because they don't affect debuggability.

Comment: @StoryTeller If you say the elision occurs for debug build too, then it happens in different strange ways... I want to understand these ways. Release is clear.

Comment: It's not that strange. I asked about your build options (language standard for one) for a reason. The sort of optimizations a compiler can and will do depend on *alot* of factors. You can't just reduce it to *debug* vs *release*.

Comment: To be honest, id be very surprised if a debug build decided to turn off copy elision over a release build. Move and copy constructors can have side effects so it may cause code to behave differently.

Comment: In C++14 mode with `-fno-elide-constructors` you'll get the behaviour you expected I suspect. At least I do in clang++/g++. In C++17 mode, I don't either.

Comment: I am using the latest VS 2017 with default /std option which according to the docs "By default, /std:c++14 is specified".

Comment: I get the same in VS2017 (C++14 mode).

Comment: GCC acts differently. It only shows "default constructor", same as for release build.

Comment: `g++ -std=c++14 -fno-elide-constructors` gives me `default`+`move`+`move`. Switching to `c++17` gives `default`+`move`. Removing `-fno-elide-constructors` results in `default` only for both c++14 and 17.

Comment: Just a note. Unless this is for research purposes, you shouldn't rely on sideeffects of copy/move constructors/destructor, since, as you noticed, compilers are free to do optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to copy elision in C++17. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are permitted, but not required to omit the copy and move (since C++11) construction of class objects even if the copy/move (since C++11) constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects.
>   [...]
>   In the initialization of an object, when the source object is a nameless temporary and is of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the target object. When the nameless temporary is the operand of a return statement, this variant of copy elision is known as RVO, "return value optimization".
>   **This optimization is mandatory; see above. (since C++17)**

See also copy initialization. Also from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization):

> The effects of copy initialization are:
>   First, if T is a class type and the initializer is a prvalue expression whose cv-unqualified type is the same class as T, the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object: see copy elision (since C++17)

Note that this is not NRVO (**Named** Return Value Optimization). This is RVO.

In C++14, the optimization does not take place if you don't want it to (see `-fno-elide-constructors`).
[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be1932746a6e7b86) (with GCC, but Clang produces the same result)

In C++17, it is mandatory, so it does take place.
[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bfe8d3c3d041518) (again, GCC but Clang agrees)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. It seems VS2017 and GCC acts differently. GCC only outputs "default constructor" (as probably it should be), while VS2017 outputs "default constructor" + "move constructor".

Comment: @JollyRoger Probably because it doesn't implement the mandatory copy elision. See [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/97479/vc-2017-guranteed-copy-elision-doesnt-work-in-some.html), it looks like it is implemented in a more recent release. Maybe update your compiler?

Comment: But still you have a move in all the cases. I do not have it any move with GCC and only in some case with VS2017. Something is wrong.

Comment: I expect no move with copy/move elision active.

Comment: `-fno-elide-constructors` deactivates copy elision for GCC and Clang. Without it, of course you don't have any move.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are two elision cases that should occur: one for the return statement and the other for initialization. Without any elision, the output should be: default constructor, move constructor, move constructor. Some compiler offers the options to disable elision. Tested with GCC with -fno-elide-constructors and this behavior was confirmed.

Now, with elision enabled, the behavior depends especially on the C++ standard used (C++11/C++14/C++17) and second it seems also on the compiler. There are elision cases that occur since C++11, others since C++14, and others since C++17.

In the case 2, GCC C++14 (and C++11) applies both elisions, where MSVC C++14 compiler applies only one (not yet identified which one).